# does numpy support indexing (in the database sense)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very large matrix, with each line containing an ID and a number of coordinates. I need to refer to lines by this ID, and performance is critical. In a database, creating an index on this field would solve the problem. Does numpy support something similar?

note: The ID is not continuous, so it can't be mapped to line number. Also, using a `dict` is out of question because of memory consumption.

Comment: Use `np.unique(..., return_inverse=1)` to convert to consecutive numbers and thus indexing in NumPy way would be possible.

Comment: @Divakar: Thanks, good idea!!

Comment: So several lines can have the same ID? I don't quite understand the question and how `np.unique` helps.

Comment: Are your keys sorted or sortable? What's a typical access pattern? Several in one go or many small random accesses? (Sorry, never seen a database.)

Comment: No, ID is just a unique identifier, no ordering guaranteed. Random access , one pattern at a time

Comment: `pandas` has a well developed indexing system, even multilevel.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thank  you, I had not used it.